# Pipe output from shell command to a python script

Tags: python, unix

I want to run a `mysql` command and set the output of that to be a variable in my python script.

Here is the shell command I'm trying to run:

```
$ mysql my_database --html -e "select * from limbs" | ./script.py
```

Here is the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def hello(variable):
    print variable
```

How would I accept the variable in the python script and have it print the output?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You need to read from stdin to retrieve the data in the python script e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

def hello(variable):
    print variable

data = sys.stdin.read()
hello(data)
```

If all you want to do here is grab some data from a mysql database and then manipulate it with Python I would skip piping it into the script and just use [the Python MySql module](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/) to do the SQL query.

Comment: It looks like the shebang is important, which is why none of the other examples worked. Without it, it will just hang forever instead.

Answer (score 37):

If you want your script to behave like many unix command line tools and accept a pipe or a filename as first argument, you can use the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

# use stdin if it's full                                                        
if not sys.stdin.isatty():
    input_stream = sys.stdin

# otherwise, read the given filename                                            
else:
    try:
        input_filename = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        message = 'need filename as first argument if stdin is not full'
        raise IndexError(message)
    else:
        input_stream = open(input_filename, 'rU')

for line in input_stream:
    print(line) # do something useful with each line
```

Answer (score 17):

When you pipe the output of one command to a pytho script, it goes to sys.stdin. You can read from sys.stdin just like a file. Example:

```
import sys

print sys.stdin.read()
```

This program literally outputs its input.

Comment: +1 for mentioning "just like a file", which will hopefully lead the OP to realize he can also do things like "for line in sys.stdin:", etc.

Answer (score 11):

Since this answer pops up on Google at the top when searching for `piping data to a python script`, I'd like to add another method, which I have found in [J. Beazley's Python Cookbook][1] after searching for a less 'gritty' aproach than using `sys`. IMO, more pythonic and self-explanatory even to new users.

```
import fileinput
with fileinput.input() as f_input:
    for line in f_input:
        print(line, end='')
```

This approach also works for commands structured like this:

```
$ ls | ./filein.py          # Prints a directory listing to stdout.
$ ./filein.py /etc/passwd   # Reads /etc/passwd to stdout.
$ ./filein.py < /etc/passwd # Reads /etc/passwd to stdout.
```

If you require more complex solutions, you can compine `argparse` and `fileinput` [as shown in this gist by martinth][2]:

```
import argparse
import fileinput

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--dummy', help='dummy argument')
    parser.add_argument('files', metavar='FILE', nargs='*', help='files to read, if empty, stdin is used')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # If you would call fileinput.input() without files it would try to process all arguments.
    # We pass '-' as only file when argparse got no files which will cause fileinput to read from stdin
    for line in fileinput.input(files=args.files if len(args.files) > 0 else ('-', )):
        print(line)
```

```
  [1]: https://library.oreilly.com/book/0636920027072/python-cookbook-3rd-edition/199.xhtml?ref=toc#_accepting_script_input_via_redirection_pipes_or_input_files
  [2]: https://gist.github.com/martinth/ed991fb8cdcac3dfadf7
```

Comment: Getting an error with this method (using python 2.7)   

    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "./pipetome.py", line 4, in <module>
    with fileinput.input() as f_input:
    AttributeError: FileInput instance has no attribute '__exit__'

Comment: The above was only tested in Python3 - perhaps instead of `with` try `f_input = fileinput.input()` ?

Comment: but how to differentiate args and stdin, e.g send_mail -to xxx@xxx.com -subject 'passwd' < /etc/passwd

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example solving your stated problem.

Comment: I had to `line.strip()` before using it for reading the piped in file.

Comment: FYI: Line 1 should be import argparse not argpase ;-)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the command line tool `xargs`

`echo 'arg1' | xargs python script.py`

`arg1` is now accessible from `sys.argv[1]` in `script.py`

Comment: This does not appear to be working with multi-line pipe contents.

Comment: @ZephaniahGrunschlag I think that is the same as giving an additional CLI argument, like: `python script.py "gday"`. A one-liner without `xargs` dependence would be nice.

Comment: I think my answer was out of context, so I deleted it

Comment: Drawbacks to the xargs approach is discussed in [How to pipe input to python...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658512/how-to-pipe-input-to-python-line-by-line-from-linux-program)

Answer (score 6):

The *one-liner* that also works for **Windows** and on `Python 3.10.3` is using `sys.stdin.read()`, like this:

```sh
echo 'Hello!' | python -c "import sys;d=sys.stdin.read(); print('{}\n'.format(d))"
```

Comment: This also works in MacOS and Linux, and is the form I was looking for... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this trying to pipe a bash command to a python script that I did not write (and didn't want to modify to accept `sys.stdin`).  I found process substitution mentioned here (https://superuser.com/questions/461946/can-i-use-pipe-output-as-a-shell-script-argument) to work fine.

Ex. 
`some_script.py -arg1 <(bash command)`