# How to pass output of one script as input of other script

Tags: python

I need to pass output of bash shell to the python script.

1. I am opening one emulator and once will get error message on terminal
2. I want to parse some data from stdout and stderr using python script
3. once parsing is done I want to terminate emulator(which is opened in bash script)

I tried using pipe-lining but here python script is not getting started until manually I'm not terminating emulator.
eg:

```
./start.sh | python file.py
```

I want to achieve automation.
I want to stream output of one script to input to python script.

Can you suggest a way to achieve streaming in the two scripts?

Regards,
Mann

Comment: I believe this question has been answered already (you need to use sys.stdin.read()): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109859/pipe-output-from-shell-command-to-a-python-script

Comment: it's not a duplicate. The OP is asking how to stop the original simulation once the python program has stopped. ( I think...)