# Piping input into a python file using powershell

Tags: python, powershell, pipeline

Hello I am trying to pipe the input from a data file as command line input using power shell.

I am using the command `cat D:\Python\test-inputs.txt| python a3p1.py`

The output should be outlying the process from the file. I am reading my stdin input with

```
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        breakdown(database, word)
```

Can anyone help me

Comment: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17658680/8794595) Pythons standard input is probably the correct approach

Answer (score 0):

It might be a bit cleaner to do something like this:

```
foreach ($line in (cat inputs.txt) {
    python a3p1.py $line
}
```

and then you can code your python script to accept arguments which will be in the format of the lines you are inputting.

Although you could just write your python file to read the file in too.

Answer (score -1):

It's a little unclear what you're asking.

You probably want to use

```
cat D:\Python\test-inputs.txt > a3p1.py
```

`|` is for piping `STDOUT` from a program into another program's `STDIN`, `>` is for piping `STDOUT` (from `cat` in this case) into a file.

Alternatively, to use `test-inputs.txt` as `STDIN` for your python program, you can use:

```
python a3p1.py < test-inputs.txt
```

Comment: You can use a `|` to pipe from stdout of `cat` into a python program as the OP suggested.