# Binding / piping output of run() on/into function in python3 (lynux)

Tags: python, parallel-processing, subprocess, function-binding

I am trying to use output of external program run using the **run** function.
this program regularly throws a row of data which i need to use in mine script
I have found a **subprocess** library and used its `run()`/`check_output()`
**Example:**
 
`def usual_process():
    # some code here
for i in subprocess.check_output(['foo','$$']):
    some_function(i)`

Now assuming that foo is already in a PATH variable and it outputs a string in semi-random periods.
I want the program to do its own things, and run `some_function(i)`every time foo sends new row to its output.

which boiles to two problems. piping the output into a for loop and running this as a background subprocess
Thank you

---

Update: I have managed to get the foo output onto some_function using [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658512/how-to-pipe-input-to-python-line-by-line-from-linux-program)

```
with os.popen('foo') as foos_output:
    for line in foos_output:
        some_function(line)
```

According to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) *os.popen* is to be deprecated, but I am yet to figure out how to pipe internal processes in python 
Now just need to figure out how to run this function in a background

Comment: Do you mean `linux`? If so, which distro?

Comment: While I am programing and testing om mine Gentoo,<br/> I am trying to limit distro-specific code to minimum and stick to Pyton3 if possible. The resulting code will be mostly targeting Raspbian at first but in a latter version android. Intention is prity much to be updating the variable based on _foo_'s output, while the program does other things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO, I have solved it.
First step was to start the external script:
    `proc=Popen('./cisla.sh', stdout=PIPE, bufsize=1)`

Next I have started a function that would read it and passed it a pipe

```
def foo(proc, **args):
       for i in proc.stdout:
         '''Do all I want to do with each'''

foo(proc).start()`
```

Limitations are:
If your wish t catch scripts error you would have to pipe it in.
second is that it leaves a zombie if you kill parrent SO dont forget to kill child in signal-handling