# Python: Catch file output of an executable

Tags: python, subprocess

I am calling an executable from a python script using `subprocess` and later doing couple of stuff on the file that the executable gives as output, by reading it separately. Is it possible to catch this output file as a file object or by any other method, and not have the file created?

Edit: I'm on Xubuntu and I am a beginner at bash scripting. The executable reads two files from a directory (path known, but separate from the one where my code is), and writes one output file there itself. I can't pipe std output instead of reading the file.

Comment: @Coldspeed don't be so hasty. There are tricky things you can achieve with files, depending upon your setup.

Comment: @PeterWood You mean something like redirecting all output to `subprocess.Popen`?

Comment: @PeterWood I will be creating thousands of files because of that third party executable. Wouldn't it be better if I can get the file information directly, rather than reading it separately, then deleting each file once I am done with it?

Comment: This is a very broad question. What operating system are you on? Can you specify where files are written? Can you pipe std output instead? Lots of loose ends. See [ask].

Comment: this question is a duplicate of this one: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43302064/binding-piping-output-of-run-on-into-function-in-python3-lynux/44488295#44488295) of mine

Comment: @PeterWood Sorry. I'm on Xubuntu and I am a beginner at bash scripting. The executable reads two files from a directory (separate from the one where my code is), and writes one output file there itself. I can't pipe std output instead.

Comment: @Tomas Is it? I can't get the file info from stdout, unlike you.